# Read Cookie PHPSESSID in opencart:2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I want to use an opencart database for another website, so users don't need to register their details again.

For example: I sell Clothes (unStitched) on opencart and I also give services for stitching them. Opencart doesn't have a module to do this, so I want to redirect users to another website and there I want to read the user details for further processing.

How can I read PHPSESSID cookie? How does opencart read firstname on edit profile forms?

```
<?php echo $firstname; ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to look at the controller for the page you're pasting the code from

Comment: can you explain little more like, where do PHPSESSID decode will be?

Comment: Are you just looking to get the current SessionID?

Comment: yes, i want to share it with next url.

Comment: What do you mean by "read cookie"? Have you tried to check `$_COOKIE` and what's stored inside?

Comment: @Anmolsingh did the provided answer assist you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work with the Session data in an Opencart view, you will need to add some code to the controller. First we need to add an item in the `$data` array that the controller uses to pass variables to the view:

Assuming you want to show this link in a product view, you will need to edit the product controller's `index` action.

Controller file: `public_html\catalog\controller\product\product.php`

Find this line:

```
if ($product_info) {
```

Add the text inside the brace:

```
    $data['mysessionvariable'] = $this->session;
```

You can restrict the available data to the sessionID only using the code below:

```
    $data['mysessionvariable'] = $this->session->getId();
```

Now the relevant PHP Session data is available to the view, you can simply reference the session variable in the view wherever your need to. e.g. `echo $mysessionvariable['session_id'];` or `echo $mysessionvariable;`

View file: `public_html\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\product.tpl`